# NGINX handling $_GET query parameters differently to Apache

Tags: apache, nginx, get

I'm currently migrating a website from an Apache build that contains the following .htaccess rules:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^$          index.php       [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}         !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}         !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|captcha|print|pdf\.php|robots\.txt)
  RewriteRule (.*)        index.php?req=$1  [QSA,L]
</ifmodule>
```

I've setup NGINX and added the following location block:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri /index.php?req=$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

This works for most pages, but some internal pages that handle query string are failing. After some debugging, I found that dumping `$_GET` was returning differently. The Apache server is returning:

```
array(2) { ["req"]=> string(8) "checkout" ["quick"]=> string(23) "email@address.com" }
```

which works perfectly for this old website, but the NGINX server is returning:

```
array(1) { ["req"]=> string(39) "/checkout?quick=email@address.com" }
```

Can anybody help me understand what's going on? It seems there's an issue with me  passing `req`, as well as additional query params.

**Update:** I've managed to partly resolve this with the following NGINX settings, but it's annoying I have to manually exclude every path I don't want to be rewritten:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?req=$1 last;
}
    
location /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$is_args$args;
}
    
location /js/ {
    # Do nothing. nginx will serve files as usual.
}
    
location /css/ {
    # Do nothing. nginx will serve files as usual.
}
    
location /images/ {
    # Do nothing. nginx will serve files as usual.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my issue with the following:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?req=$1 last;
    }
}
```

which should prevent rewriting of non-request filenames.